# Mail configuration settings changes in the .env file not taking effect in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, email

I initially had my mail configuration settings in my .env file pointing to my gmail account and contact form was working fine. I have now changed my settings to point to a webmail and run php artisan config:cache but the mail is still being sent to my gmail. Below is my configuration settings and I've also tested the web mail by sending an email to it via gmail and sending back to gmail from the web mail and it's working fine. Any assistance is highly appreciated.

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mywebmail
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=sales@mydomain
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=sales@mydomain
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Laravel"
```

PS: My config/Mail.php

```
<?php

return [

    'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),

    'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],

        'ses' => [
            'transport' => 'ses',
        ],

        'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
        ],

        'postmark' => [
            'transport' => 'postmark',
        ],

        'sendmail' => [
            'transport' => 'sendmail',
            'path' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'transport' => 'log',
            'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
        ],

        'array' => [
            'transport' => 'array',
        ],
    ],

   

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

   
    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

Comment: Check in config/mail.php and try php artisan optimize:clear and php artisan optimize

Comment: After the config:cache command the new settings should be applied.  I would check if config/mail.php uses the env

Comment: @ApurvBhavsar `php artisan optimize` is not needed after the clear & normally config:cache would be enough.

Comment: If your mail is being queued and sent that way, you should also do a `php artisan queue:restart` so that anything stored in memory there is also refreshed with your recent changes.

Comment: @ApurvBhavsar what exactly I'm I supposed to look in config/mail? I've added the file's  code as well in my question.

Comment: @wblommaert How do I check that? Tried the command though but it hasn't helped yet.

Comment: you should change the MAIL_MAILER to sendmail in .env file and then clear config cache

Comment: @Amir tried it didn't work. I faile to understand how that would be the problem! I was sending to gmail initially and it worked well. Changing settings to use webmail instead of gmail configurations it's still using the gmail configurations. Shouldn't this be a caching problem? I stand corrected!

Comment: @Amir Sorry, I changed the MAIL_MAILER but forgot to run php artisan config:cache. After running the command and submitting the form I get the following error ```Swift_TransportException
Expected response code 220 but got an empty response```

Comment: btw its sendmail, I am not sure what the issue is but you can contact the email provider and ask them for the configurations such as port, encryption etc...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was in my controller. I was sending email to my gmail instead of my webmail. I forgot to change that when I changed the mail settings. After changing mygmail to my webmail it works just fine.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data =  $request->validate([
            //
        ]);

        Mail::to('mygmail.com')
            ->send(new ContactMe($data));

        return redirect(route('contact-us.index'))->with('flash', "Thank you, 
                                                    we'll be in touch soon");
    }
```